# Circular buffer DataFrame for handling streaming data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am receiving data every minute from an API and I execute some basic technical indicators each time. What I am doing up until now is append the new data to my existing DataFrame and calculate the indicators (MA, RSI, etc). If I want to run this for a long time, data will pile up, while at every time I need only the last e.g. 50 rows for my indicators to work.

Is there an efficient way to handle streaming data like I would be able to do with a circular buffer but with pandas dataframes?